# OsmAnd in Android

Tags: android, maps, osmdroid

I am working on a project which uses OsmAnd for the maps. I am doing the R&D regarding the same by going through the wiki links provided. But i am not getting a clearcut idea regarding how to use this library in the android project.

I have searched for the tutorial as well but no luck.
Could anybody help me out with the same by directing me to some tutorial for the basic understanding or by providing the steps of using OSMAnd in android application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OsmAnd is a standalone application and it's not intended to be used as a library.

Here is a suggestion to developers to allow that and their answer. https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/osmand/7q83Mrc449Y

Comment: I am using OSMDroid jar in my application which is inturn using OSM Data. Thanks for the reply.